# Filter around 2000 email address out of an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of around 2000 different email addresses that need to be excluded from an Excel file.

I cannot look for the 2000 manually since this is a daily process.

How can I accomplish this with VBA to create a filter with all email addresses that need to be excluded?

Comment: Add a helper column match or vlookup your email list against the 2000 email list and then filter by your helper column. No VBA at all.

Comment: Where do you have this list of 2000 email addresses stored? In a text file? Excel? A SQL database?

Comment: They come from SQL database but I just get the excel file with all of them.

Comment: @Jay The list of 2000 email addresses is stored separately in SQL from the full dump that you get as an Excel file? If so you could pull them into another worksheet as PEH mentioned above and filter. You could use a bit of VBA to do this and also to make that helper sheet 'hidden or 'very hidden' depending on what happens next in the Excel file's life (do you discard it, does it get sent to office workers, etc.).

Comment: I don´t have access to the database or views, I pull the report from Microsoft Dynamics. Also, forgot to mention that no only complete emails are in the list also domains that need to be excluded.

Comment: Do you need to filter out all of the email addresses or only a part of them?

Comment: All of them, they are all exceptions and need to be excluded. Also they be more in the future

Comment: The vlookup won´t do because as I said there are also domain and not only specific email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all guys, at the end I used advance filtering and it gave me all the emails I need to remove, I created a macro to apply the filter as many times as I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with formulas that also filters for domains (not only full addresses):

[image]

The formula in column B is:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A:A,D:D,0)>0,IFERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND("@",A:A)+1),D:D,0)>0,FALSE)),"yes","no")
```

The list in column D is the list of 2000 emails you want to filter for and it could also be in another worksheet (formula needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Note that the first 2 addresses get a `yes` because their domain is in the filter list.